# Is there a way to find out if there are Airbnbs in historic buildings that have been converted to condos?

Tags: history, airbnb

Occasionally, old historic buildings are converted to condos and the individual units within them sold – like the [Eastern Columbia Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Columbia_Building) in Los Angeles, the [Tribune Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribune_Tower) in Chicago, etc. For that matter, an Airbnb in a [pencil tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_tower) could be interesting too.

Since they're condos, I most likely can't go inside them but I'd love to do an Airbnb or Vrbo or whatever inside them. Unfortunately, Airbnb doesn't give the exact address of rentals until you actually pay.

Google searches for "Airbnb Eastern Columbia" return a lot of results that don't go into the specifics w.r.t. the location. They might be in cool historic buildings, which would pique my interest, but it's just hard to tell.

Is there a way to find out if there are Airbnbs in specific buildings, or what Airbnbs are in historic buildings in a given city?

Comment: Is this restricted to a single country (or an even smaller area) or world wide?

Comment: Doesn't AirBnB let you search down to very specific areas? I can search my neighbourhood. It won't give you an exact address, but it will narrow it down to a very few hosts near the building you are interested in, and if it's a historic building you should be able to work out if it's the one you are interested in.

Comment: @DJClayworth - so let's consider the Eastern Columbia building. it's in dt LA, bounded by 8th, 9th, Broadway and Hill streets. the two hits that I get for that area are https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/44336872 and https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/44337800. they have pics of the interior but I can't tell from the interior what the specific building is. i could contact the host but idk that seems like that could potentially be a fishing expedition.

Comment: @Willeke - in-so-far as I know airbnb does this for every country? I've never tried to look up airbnb's for countries other than the US

Comment: @neubert Those are the same building and both have pictures of Eastern Columbia in the views from it, so neither are it. I would have asked both if I wasn't sure, but I'm just making suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huntbnb [used to](https://www.fastcompany.com/3034294/this-website-snitches-on-renters-who-list-their-apartments-on-airbnb) list Airbnb listings given an address but it closed. The 3 very imperfect solutions I am aware of are:

1. Look at the picture of the Airbnb listings near the address and see whether any seems to be taken from the address, e.g., by comparing against pictures from Google Maps or Zillow. You could also use Google reverse image search, eg in your example https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/44337800, I found your Airbnb address on https://www.livabl.com/2020/10/825-south-hill-dtla-pet-friendly.html via reverse image search. Some Airbnb pictures are even a map with the address location.
2. Ask the Airbnb host.
3. The reviews may reveal the information if the building is atypical, e.g. historic ("The building is 2-century old so the sound isolation is inexistent").

Comment: You might also try Google search for CityName+Historical. Sometimes a good listing might pop up.

Comment: Reading up on the huntbnb link I guess airbnb made the change to make it so people leasing apartments could be airbnb hosts without the apartment finding out. Seems kinda shady on airbnb's part but they also make it harder to use cases like mine. Maybe they could make hiding the location optional. Hide the location by default and show it if you specifically think the location is a draw.

Comment: @neubert I'd vote to make hiding the location optional. No need to waste human time inferring Airbnb addresses. Your listing's address was easy to infer though.

Comment: I guess the obscurity is partly so customers can't contact the owners directly to try and negotiate a cheaper price than the one on Airbnb. There are a lot of other companies doing apartment rentals which provide full addresses (the days when Airbnb was much cheaper than other commercial services are long gone). Although the question was only about Airbnb